# How to solve this? ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out fatal

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

whenever I try to run  `git pull upstream master -X ours`
I get an error below:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I literally followed almost every solution I could find online but nothing has resolved it yet.. Can somebody please help with this? Thanks

Comment: Please share some of the solutions you tried, so that people don't try to give advice that's been tried and failed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a corporate environment, outgoing SSH connection would typically be blocked. Or it could be a [GFW side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) (although Hong Kong is supposed to be not impacted).

In any case, the fist tests are to check access and switch to HTTPS, to see if it works then:

- `ping github.com`
- `cd /path/to/repo`; `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/<myRepo>`

Answer (score 2):

For me reconnecting wifi connection and VPN connection solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue. As usual after coding I always push the code. But this time it didn't work. I followed Many tuts to solve this problem. But end up when I realize my VPN was switched ON already. But before that I applied below command:

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/repo-name

And it worked.